# Update a field in a case every time there is an email associated with that case?

Tags: case

I'm looking for a way to increment a number field timesUpdated__c on a Case every time there is an email in that Case. I was thinking of using the Process Builder but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it. Any help?

Comment: did you try Process Builder on Creation of SObject EmailMessage?  Clicks not code is generally preferred by many in SFSE

Comment: There doesn't look like there's a way to interact with the fields of a parent case through process builder.

Comment: see https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BHvJIAW

Answer (score 2):

You can create a workflow on the Email object, add the following criteria:
Email Message: Is Incoming EQUALS True, 
And then add a field update action to update the custom field on the parent case

Comment: Are you sure cross-object field update is allowed in this case? I would think you'd need to use Process Builder.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented this specific workflow in my org